# Designing an Application with different ViewControllers

Tags: iphone, ipad

after reading a lot of tutorials and threads here on stackoverflow there is one *basic question* left in my head.

The structure of my App should be the following:

MainMenu - fullscreen without a navigation bar but 2 buttons (button1 and button2)

Page1 - should appear by pressing button1 and should have a navigation bar at the top with a "back"-button to get back to the MainMenu.

Page2 - should appear by pressing button2 without a navigation bar at the top. Page2 should be a UISplitView. There must be a back button somewhere.
*(I think this is where the problem starts, a UISplitView can't be presented modally, can it?)*

You should be able to add subpages to Page1.

So how can I do that? I don't need executable code but just a hint on how the structure of my app should be. For example where to add the navigation controller, how the MainMenu looks like.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you trying to create an Application for iPad?

Your Application's UI sems inconsistent being First View the only view without navigation Bar.

You will be using standard navigation to navigate to page1 from home page. So you will be adding a navigation Controller with Home View Controller as a Root View COntroller with hidden navigation bar.

eg.

```
-(void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:...
{
   HomeViewController * hvc = [[HomeViewController alloc]init];  
   UInavigationController * nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:hvc];
   nvc.navigationBar.hidden = YES;
   [window addSubView:nvc.view];
}
```

Then on tap of first Button you will be pushing the Page1 View Controller

```
-(IBActtion)button1Pressed:(id)sender
{
   Page1ViewCOntroller * p1vc = [[Page1ViewCOntroller alloc]init]; 
   [self.navigationController pushViewCOntroller:p1vc animated:YES];
}
```

In `viewWillAppear: method` of Page1ViewController unhide the NavigationBar and hide it in the `viewWillDisappear: method`

Your Page 2 needs to be splitViewController.
Now about Split View, Apple [says](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/General/Conceptual/iPadProgrammingGuide/UserInterface/UserInterface.html)

```
The split view controller’s view should always be installed as the root view of your application window. You should never present a split view inside of a navigation or tab bar interface.
```

But as there is no "must" written in the above statement, and since its finally a View Controller in itselt, you should be able to add it on the window or another view.

Try to create a VIewController, with split VIew added on it, and like page1, push the View on the navigation Controller.